fetch-vcr: Saving Fixture files is not supported in the browser yet
I am using "fetch-vcr" pacakage in my React Native App to mock the api response automatically.
text
i have done the setup as documented. but when i am running my e2e tests and my api is getting called i am facing issue that " [Error: fetch-vcr: Saving Fixture files is not supported in the browser yet]"
but when i am calling any api through the test case like below
  it('should fetch mock API data', async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Starting API fetch test');
      const sessionId =
        '123456abcdefgzxcvbnm';

      const response = await fetch(
        'https://qa.example.com/api/?page=1',
        {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Cookie: `_session_id=${sessionId}`,
          },
        },
      );

      const data = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in fetch test:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  });

Then my mocked data file is generating and getting stored in my ./e2e/_fixtures file
I have done the below setup
e2e/fetchVCRSetup.js
import { default as fetchVCR } from 'fetch-vcr';

fetchVCR.configure({
  fixturePath: './e2e/_fixtures',
  mode: 'record',
  node: true,
});

global.fetch = fetchVCR;

e2e/jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/e2e/fetchVCRSetup.js'],
};

How to generate mocked data file automatically ?
Whenever i am running my e2e tests and my api is getting called and i can see the response while running tests. but the mocked file is not generating
